# How to monitor programs that write to specific files?

Tags: bash, dns, systemd

I'm curious how I can show/monitor the files that a program is writing to via the command line? I understand certain processes rely on certain files to function but how do I know what files these processes use. Lets say I want to see what files the dns resolver service writes to, I know the answer is /etc/resolv.conf but how can I verify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lsof` command lists open files per process. The number of open files at any moment will be huge, so you want to be a bit specific.

- If you know the process id, do `sudo lsof -p <pid>`.
- If you know a directory that the files are located in, do `sudo lsof
  +D <directory>`.

There are many more options. See `man lsof`. Without sudo, you can only see files opened by processes you own yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strace` to monitor every system call that a process makes, including opening files for both reading and writing.

`strace` processes a lot of output. You can grep the output for `open` to review just the calls to `open files`.

See `man strace` for details. Note that is a `-f` option if you need to trace a process that forks.